# Upload Image before submit form in mvc3 asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, post, file-upload

i am using asp.net MVC3

I want to upload the image before form is submit.

below is my code

```
 <div>
   @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveData", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype =      "multipart/form-data" }))
   {
     <div> Image: 
           <input type="file" name="uploadFile" onchange="upload(this);" /></div>
     <div> Name: 
           @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)</div>
     <div> Address:  
           @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address)</div>
     <div> Phone: 
           @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Phone)</div>

     <input type="submit" name="save" id="savedata" title="save" 
        value="save"  />
}         
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function UploadFile(image) {
        //call controller action UploadFile
         $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "Home/UploadFile",
            data: image,       //This is wrong
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"
        });
   }
</script>
```

Now on Controller side

```
 public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile)
 {
     //save image
 }
```

can any one can suggest how can i upload the image before posting my form to save data.

Answer (score 1):

`$.ajax()` is not capable of that. There are jQuery plugins available though, that do this for you. [Here's one](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/09/html5-file-upload-jquery-php/). [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload) also discusses loads of options to do this. Do note that file upload through AJAX is a relatively new feature and [not all browsers support it](http://caniuse.com/#search=FormData).